# Adding order buttons to a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an example from this gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nome")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And I would like to add a button for ordering the data in each column.

Somebody can help me find the best way to do this?

Comment: by "orden" do you mean order? Do you want to sort?

Comment: What part are you having troubles with? Adding the buttons, or the actual sorting?

Comment: Gridview3.AllowSorting=True.  This will allow you to select the header titles to sort by that column

Comment: I want to know what the best way to add the buttons and order the data, its better user a function or a griedview command? Or is another better way?

Comment: You question has too many typos; community has to edit your question 6 times. Please kindly put a little effort on asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting is built into the GridView control.  There is a control Property called `AllowSorting`, set this to True and you can sort columns by clicking on the header row titles.

There is no need to add extra buttons, even if you want to do some type of special sorting, you'd still Handle the `Sorting` event and implement your own methods

Comment: Ok, thaks in the Sorting event I can know if the griedview is order by ASC or DESC? So I can order by DESC if is ASC.

Comment: Inside the event inspect `e.SortDirection` .  But FYI, clicking the header is a toggle so you need not manage the direction change yourself. You should read up on [Gridview.AllowSorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowsorting(v=vs.110).aspx) property